# render function is returning empty div in tests after upgrading my react project from v16 to v18

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

### UPDATE

After reviewing more of my tests I have found this behavior to be inconsistent. I have very similar tests and some render and perform as expected after the update, but others return the empty div. Does anyone have any insight on what the issue may be?

---

Recently at work I updated our ui from using React v16 to v18. I also updated the dev dependencies as recommended. Some of my tests are working just fine, specifically ones that test routes and functionality after the element is rendered based on a route. Imports are the same in both test scenarios.

```
// Sample Component
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export default function MyModal({
show,
message
}) {
if (!show) {
  return null;
}
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

return (
 <Modal
  show={visible}
  data-testid={"myComponent-modal"}
 >
  <Modal.Body>
    {message}
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button>Ok</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
 </Modal
);
}
```

Testing some route that eventually will show MyModal component after some simulated actions.

```
// Test details
const {getByRole} = render(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/somePath"]}>
   <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
    <Routes>
     <Route
       path="/somePath"
       element={<MyComponent {...props} />}
     />
    </Routes>
   </UserContext.Provider>
  </MemoryRouter>
);

// fill in some form detail, then click submit button, then myModal appears

// Result is everything renders as I expect and test passes.
```

Other tests, specifically ones where I am just trying to render a component, are just returning an empty div to me from the render function.

```
// Test Details
// This is an MRE not my actual test as I can't that code
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"
import React from "react";
import MyModal from "../../components/MyModal";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

const {queryByText} = render(
  <MyModal show={true} message={"Test Message"} />
);
screen.debug();
const modalMessage = queryByText("Test Message");
expect(modalMessage).toBeInTheDocument();


// Result: assertion fails
// screen.debug() returns <body><div /></body>
```

```
Dev Dependencies
@testing-library/dom: "^8.5.0"
@testing-library/jest-dom: "^5.11.10"
@testing-library/react: "^13.4.0"
@testing-library/react-hooks: "^7.0.2"
@testing-library/user-event: "^13.5.0"
react-test-renderer: "^18.2.0"
react-testing-library: "^7.0.1"
jest: "^26.6.3"
jest-cli: "^26.6.3"
jest-junit: "^6.2.1"
jest-mock-axios: "^4.2.1"
jsdom: "11.9.0"
```

We have several other dev dependencies, but none that I believe would be affecting these tests.

I have tried changing dev dependency versions, as not all have been updated to latest, but that didn't seem to work. I have downgraded them all back, but that seems to run the tests in react v17 not 18 which isn't desired.
I've tried debugging, but am struggling there. When it reaches the line to render the component it seems to jump up to the test signature and not into my component where I have break points then eventually back down to the test, but at that point it's already an empty div element.
I've tried looking through blogs other posts, but am either not finding any solution or have found other posts with my same issue where no answers have been provided.
I've also tried waiting after the render, but that didn't seem to help.
I tried wrapping the component within a MemoryRouter.
It just seems as though render is not even trying to render my component.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. As frustrating as this has been to resolve I am still loving the developer life. Happy coding to everyone!!!